# Using Python Script to post data to web server

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, post

I am using Python 2.7.3 and I am trying to post data to my local web server. The data I am posting is temperature readings from my raspberry pi. I know the url is right because if I use the postman chrome plugin the data is successfully posted and I get a return message. In postman I can only use form-data though and NOT x-www-form-urlencoded which is how my python script has the content type setup. Can I change it to form-data?

Python Code:

```
import os
import glob
import time
import threading
import urllib
import urllib2

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
    temperature = {'tempf':temp_f, 'tempc':temp_c}
        return temperature

def post():
    threading.Timer(1800.0, post).start()
    temperature = read_temp()
    data = temperature
    data['room'] = 'Server Room'
    print(data)

    data=urllib.urlencode(data)
    path='http://client.pathtophppage'    #the url you want to POST to
    req=urllib2.Request(path, data)
    req.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    page=urllib2.urlopen(req).read()


post()
```

And the Error:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Documents $ python Temperature.py 
{'tempc': 22.0, 'tempf': 71.6, 'room': 'Server Room'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Temperature.py", line 49, in <module>
    post()  
  File "Temperature.py", line 45, in post
    page=urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 520, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 439, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 379, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 626, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 520, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 445, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 379, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 528, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Comment: The logging indicates a HTTP500 error from the _server_. It makes sense to put the server in debug mode and see why it's ging an error. My guess is that is expects different POST data than it's getting and it doesn't implement a proper HTTP400 request check.

Comment: Using the answer I selected I was able to receive a response from my PHP page. Although the response was an error about null constraints which is my next problem to fix lol.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

save your time, use this [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) lib for httpRequests,

simple app

```
import requests

url = 'http://url.com'
query = {'field': value}
res = requests.post(url, data=query)
print(res.text)
```

Comment: How will the website handle the request?

Comment: How to you put that data on the website?