# Python script to retrieve data from MySQL and post it to web server

Tags: python, json, post, webserver

I am trying to come up with a python script to retrieve data from MySQL and post the data in json format to a web server. I have two separate python codes, one for retrieving the data in MySQL and one for posting the data in json format. The main issue that I am facing is that I do not know how to integrate them together.

**Code for retrieving data from MySQL:**

```
   import MySQLdb 
   db = MySQLdb.connect("locahost", "root", "12345", "testdatabase") 
   curs=db.cursor() 
   curs.execute("SELECT * from mydata")
   reading = curs.fetchall() 
   print "Data Info: %s" % reading
```

**Code for posting to web server:**

```
import json
import urllib2
import requests

data = {
       'ID' :1
       'Name' :Bryan
       'Class' :3A
}
req = urllib2.Request('http://abcd.com') //not the actual url
req.add_header('Content type', 'application/json')
response=urllib.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))
```

I have referenced the codes from the following links:

[Retrieve data from MySQL](https://scriptingmysql.wordpress.com/2011/09/09/retrieving-data-from-mysql-via-python/)

[Retrieve data from MySQL 2nd link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm)

[Post to web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459762/using-python-script-to-post-data-to-web-server)

[Post to web server 2nd link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322430/how-to-send-post-request)

Would appreciate any form of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the connection as a library file,

**File connection.py :**

```
def db_connect(query):
    import MySQLdb db = MySQLdb.connect("locahost", "root", "12345", "testdatabase") 
    curs=db.cursor() 
    curs.execute(query)
    reading = curs.fetchall() 
    return reading
```

**Main file: webserver.py**

```
import json
import urllib2
import requests
import connection   

mysql_data = connection.db_connect("SELECT * from mydata")
#data = <Your logic to convert string to json>
req = urllib2.Request('http://abcd.com') //not the actual url
req.add_header('Content type', 'application/json')
response=urllib.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))
```

**Method 2** you can also try sql alachemy which gives directly dict data out of sql query. You can use filters instead of direct sql query.

I recomend this way is better and you can go through the link "https://pythonspot.com/en/orm-with-sqlalchemy/"

Comment: From your code, you are using webserver.py to run connection.py to do the sql database connection right?

Comment: Also, for the db_connect(query) in connection.py, what does the query refer to?

Comment: @gram95 query refers to the string which you pass it from webserver.py (see line mysql_data = ) where you pass the query string.

Comment: So, I replace it with mysql_data? Sorry, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: It is very basic thing how do you call a function with arguments? in (mysql_data = connection.db_connect("SELECT * from mydata") you are passing the query to "connection.db_connect" and there you use this string in a variable called query.

Comment: @gram95 yes thanks, and as I mentioned the better way to go is use something like sqlalchemy to connect with DB , so that you can write query as filter and it will be returning in data type dictionary.  Please accept this answer if you feel as correct

Answer (score -1):

```
def db_connect(query):
    import MySQLdb db = MySQLdb.connect("locahost", "root", "12345", "testdatabase") 
    curs=db.cursor() 
    curs.execute(query)
    reading = curs.fetchall() 
    return reading
```

Comment: Can you please add something more than just a code segment.  How should they use this code to achieve what they are trying to do?